# How to redirect out of a controller action from an ajax request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

Currently doing `redirect_to and return` still enters the `.js.erb` file, and therefore rendering some js.
Is there a way to exit the request in the controller?

Answer (score 0):

you can use below instead of `redirect_to and return`

```
redirect_to url :status => 301
```

I hope this will help you.